# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Request had invalid authentication credentials

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've performed the setup of Firebase messaging a while ago in my Spring Boot project:

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    FirebaseProperties firebaseProperties;

    @Bean
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials() {
        try {
            if (firebaseProperties.getServiceAccount() != null) {
                try (InputStream is = firebaseProperties.getServiceAccount().getInputStream()) {
                    return GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is);
                }
            } else {
                // Use standard credentials chain. Useful when running inside GKE
                return GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp(GoogleCredentials credentials) {
        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build();

        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    @Bean
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging(FirebaseApp firebaseApp) {
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);
    }
}
```

In pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

It has been working well for quite a while, but then suddenly it stopped working today with the following message:

> Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2
> access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
> See
> https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

The above error appears on call to `FirebaseMessaging` `sendAll()` method.

I didn't change anything in the configuration. Does anyone know the reason for this sudden error and how to fix this? Could this be a temporary glitch? At the moment of writing I see that Firebase Status is all green.

**Update 1:**

It seems though that the issue only persists when using the Firebase Authentication Emulator locally. I set the following environment variable to use the local auth emulator:

FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="my.computer.ip.address:9099"

Comment: If you think the problem is not with your code or configuration, then Stack Overflow isn't really the right place to be.  You should reach out to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) and explain the problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you. I just wrote to Firebase support. I will come back here with updates in case there are any. Would be great if this is solved and also helpful for future readers.

Comment: @DougStevenson It seems that the issue persists only when using the Firebase Authentication Emulator locally. When the Cloud Firebase Authentication is used - no issues.